# Access Using Inner Join to select 1 record from another table with the Max Date

Tags: sql, ms-access

I wrote this following query in Access.

I finally got it Save without errors but When I click on DataSheet View, the table displays all the records from table 2.

Table1 has unique ID and that ID is in multiple rows in table2 (1 to many). I need to only fetch the most recent record by selecting the Max(MyRecentDate). However, my return VIEW contains all the rows for the ID. How can I get this query to work to only select ONE record with the MAX Date from table2?

Thanks....

```
SELECT 
[table1].FirstName, 
[table1].MiddleName, 
[table1].LastName,  
[table2].NameDesc,
[table2].MyRecentDate



FROM [table1] 
INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT [table2].ID,  [table2].NameDesc, MAX( [table2].MyRecentDate) as MyRecentDate
            FROM    [table2]
            GROUP BY  [table2].ID,[table2].NameDesc


        ) [table2]
ON [table1].[ID] = [table2].[ID];
```

Comment: Change the select Max (..) as MaxDate and add On ... and [table2].MyRecentDate = MaxDate

Comment: I take it `NameDesc` can be different for the same `ID`?

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine. Note you can use max in place of TOP 1

```
SELECT 
[table1].FirstName, 
[table1].MiddleName, 
[table1].LastName, 
(SELECT TOP 1 [table2].NameDesc FROM [table2] WHERE [table1].[ID] = [table2].[ID]) AS NameDesc,
(SELECT TOP 1 [table2].MyRecentDate FROM [table2] WHERE [table1].[ID] = [table2].[ID]) AS MyRecentDate

FROM [table1]
```